# Multivariate K-S test in R

Tags: r, distribution, hypothesis-test

So we can run a K-S test to assess if we have a difference in the distribution of dtwo datasets, as outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

So lets take the following data

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000
var1 <- runif(N, min=0, max=0.5)
var2 <- runif(N, min=0.3, max=0.7)
var3 <- rbinom(n=N, size=1, prob = 0.45)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```

We can then seperate based on var3 outcome

```
df.1 <- subset(df, var3 == 1)
df.2 <- subset(df, var3 == 0)
```

Now we can run a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to test for differences in the distributions of each individual variable.

```
ks.test(jitter(df.1$var1), jitter(df.2$var1))
ks.test(jitter(df.1$var2), jitter(df.2$var2))
```

And not suprisngly, we do not get a difference and can assume the different dataset have been drawn from the same distribution. This can be visualised through:

```
plot(ecdf(df.1$var1), col=2)
lines(ecdf(df.2$var1))

plot(ecdf(df.1$var2), col=3)
lines(ecdf(df.2$var2), col=4)
```

But now we want to consider if the distributions between `var3==0` and `var3==1` differ when we consider both `var1` & `var2` together.
**Is there an R package to run such a test when we have a multiple predictors**

The similar question was posed [here](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/multivariate-kolmogorov-smirnov-distance-r), but has not received any answers

There appears to be some literature:
[Example 1](http://v-scheiner.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/1166/1/acat2007.pdf)
[Example 2](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/dpena/articles/kolpl97.pdf)

But nothing appears to be linked to R

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and not really a specific programming question. Perhaps it's better to ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Two dimensional KS test has been discussed in Peacock, J. A. (1983). Two-dimensional goodness-of-fit testing in astronomy. Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society, 202(3), 615–627. https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/202.3.615

There is an implementation, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Peacock.test/